Efficiently tagging first and last of each object matching condition
How can I make the code more readable and more efficient? (provided code is O(n²) time, but intuition says it can be pre-processed and done in O(n) time)
Description

it tags the first and last of each object matching a condition, and removes all objects without tags

the input order must be preserved
the first match may also be the last match (see "Bobby" example)


it must use at most ES6 functions

Input
[
    { name: "John Smith", value: 5 },
    { name: "Jane Doe", value: 3 },
    { name: "John Smith", value: 1 },
    { name: "John Smith", value: 3 },
    { name: "Jane Doe", value: 5 },
    { name: "Bobby", value: 2 },
]

Output
[
    { name: "John Smith", value: 5, tags: ["first"] },
    { name: "Jane Doe", value: 3, tags: ["first"] },
    // removed since it is not the first nor last of "John Smith": { name: "John Smith", value: 1, tags: [] },
    { name: "John Smith", value: 3, tags: ["last"] },
    { name: "Jane Doe", value: 5, tags: ["last"] },
    { name: "Bobby", value: 2, tags: ["first", "last"] },
]

Code
Only "PROCESSING" needs to be reviewed.


/* SETUP */
const arrays = [{
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Bobby",
    value: 2
  },
]

const expectedTaggedArrays = [{
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 5,
    tags: ["first"]
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 3,
    tags: ["first"]
  },
  {
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 3,
    tags: ["last"]
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 5,
    tags: ["last"]
  },
  {
    name: "Bobby",
    value: 2,
    tags: ["first", "last"]
  },
]

/* PROCESSING */
// set all elements to have empty list of tags
let taggedArrays = arrays.map((x) => ({ ...x,
  tags: []
}))

for (let i = 0; i < taggedArrays.length; i++) {
  // function to compare for "equality"
  const hasSameName = (x) => x.name === taggedArrays[i].name

  // tag if first time name seen
  const firstMatchingIndex = taggedArrays.findIndex(hasSameName)
  if (firstMatchingIndex === i) {
    taggedArrays[firstMatchingIndex].tags.push("first")
  }

  // tag if last time name seen
  const lastMatchingIndex = taggedArrays.findLastIndex(hasSameName)
  if (lastMatchingIndex === i) {
    taggedArrays[lastMatchingIndex].tags.push("last")
  }
}

// remove all elements that have not been tagged
taggedArrays = taggedArrays.filter((x) => x.tags.length)

/* TEST */
const isCorrect =
  JSON.stringify(taggedArrays) == JSON.stringify(expectedTaggedArrays)
isCorrect ? console.info("correct") : console.error("incorrect")





How can I make the code ... more efficient? provided code is O(n^2)

time complexity
This is \$O(n)\$ time complexity, following inspiration from @J_H's solution.
counting
In one pass, count the number of elements for each name:
{
    "John Smith": 3,
    "Jane Doe": 2,
    "Bobby": 1,
}

producing output
In one pass, go through each element and count as you go along. If it is the first occurence, add to the output array. If it is the last occurence, add to the output array.
code


/* SETUP */
const arrays = [{
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Bobby",
    value: 2
  },
]

const expectedTaggedArrays = [{
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 5,
    tags: ["first"]
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 3,
    tags: ["first"]
  },
  {
    name: "John Smith",
    value: 3,
    tags: ["last"]
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    value: 5,
    tags: ["last"]
  },
  {
    name: "Bobby",
    value: 2,
    tags: ["first", "last"]
  },
]

/* PROCESSING */
const counts = arrays.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const key = currentValue.name
  accumulator[key] = (accumulator[key] || 0) + 1

  return accumulator
}, {})

const seen = {}
const taggedArrays = []
arrays.forEach(currentValue => {
  const key = currentValue.name
  seen[key] = (seen[key] || 0) + 1

  const taggedObject = currentValue
  taggedObject.tags = []

  if (seen[key] === 1) {
    taggedObject.tags.push("first")
  }

  if (seen[key] === counts[key]) {
    taggedObject.tags.push("last")
  }

  if (taggedObject.tags.length) {
    taggedArrays.push(currentValue)
  }
})

/* TEST */
const isCorrect =
  JSON.stringify(taggedArrays) == JSON.stringify(expectedTaggedArrays)
isCorrect ? console.info("correct") : console.error("incorrect")




sorting

How can I make the code ... more efficient? provided code is O(n^2)

Use a stable sort
on the name field, with \$O(n \log n)\$ time complexity.
Now, with \$O(1)\$ constant memory complexity,
scan through the name entries, maintaining prev and count state variables
to detect "first" and "last" transitions.
This has the advantage of letting you stream output values,
once you've incurred the cost of the sort.
hashing
Make a first pass over the data to build up a name hash map ("object"),
storing the first and last record index seen for a given name.
These are all \$O(1)\$ constant time operations.
Then make another pass over the data to produce output records.
Memory cost is proportional to number of distinct names,
and time cost is \$O(n)\$ linear.
Initialize first and last objects, then iterate index i over the input records:

if rec.name not in first, then store first[rec.name] = i
unconditionally store last[rec.name] = i

Again iterate i over the input records:

assign empty output record
if first[rec.name] == i, then we'll produce a "first" output
if last[rec.name] == i, then we'll produce a "last" output
if non-empty output record, then emit it

Let \$d\$ be number of distinct names,
and \$n\$ be number of input records.
If \$d \ll n\$ then memory complexity is \$O(d)\$,
otherwise it is \$O(n)\$.
In any event the time complexity shall be \$O(n)\$ linear in
the size of the input.

Can you give more details on how to go from the second part of hashing to the desired output with time cost of O(n) as stated in your answer? After stable sort and the first part of your hash map solution, I would have: {"John Smith": {first: 0, last: 3}, "Jane Doe": {first: 1, last: 4}, "Bobby": {first: 5, last: 5}}. An O(n log n) solution can be made from the first part of hash map by stable sorting again.

Here is my solution. Note: I am not sure if it helps with the time complexity, but it makes the code readable.


const arrays = [
  { name: 'John Smith', value: 5 },
  { name: 'Jane Doe', value: 3 },
  { name: 'John Smith', value: 1 },
  { name: 'John Smith', value: 3 },
  { name: 'Jane Doe', value: 5 },
  { name: 'Bobby', value: 2 },
];

const groupedByName = arrays.reduce((acc, item, mainIdx) => {
  (acc[item.name] ??= []).push({ ...item, mainIdx });
  return acc;
}, {});

const finalArray = Object.values(groupedByName)
  .reduce((acc, nameArray) => {
    if (nameArray.length === 1) {
      const firstLast = { ...nameArray.at(0), tags: ['first', 'last'] };
      return [...acc, firstLast];
    }

    const first = { ...nameArray.at(0), tags: ['first'] };
    const last = { ...nameArray.at(-1), tags: ['last'] };

    return [...acc, first, last];
  }, [])
  .sort((a, b) => a.mainIdx - b.mainIdx);

console.log(finalArray);




Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].
